# aptitude - Package removal on jdk installation

Tags: java, aptitude

I tried the following command

```
aptitude install sun-java6-jdk
```

It prompts me that the following packages will be removed.

> ant{u} ant-gcj{u} ant-optional{u} ant-optional-gcj{u}
>   ca-certificates-java{u} default-jre{u} default-jre-headless{u}
>   fastjar{u} gcj-4.4-base{u} gcj-4.4-jre-lib{u} icedtea-6-jre-cacao{u}
>   icedtea-netx{u} jarwrapper{u} junit{u} junit4{u} libasm3-java{u}
>   libaudio2{u} libcommons-beanutils-java{u} libcommons-codec-java{u}
>   libcommons-collections3-java{u} libcommons-compress-java{u}
>   libcommons-digester-java{u} libcommons-el-java{u}
>   libcommons-httpclient-java{u} libcommons-logging-java{u}
>   libdb-je-java{u} libdb4.7-java{u} libdb4.7-java-gcj{u} libecj-java{u}
>   libequinox-osgi-java{u} libgcj-bc{u} libgcj-common{u} libgcj10{u}
>   libhamcrest-java{u} libice-dev{u} libicu4j-java{u} libjasper-java{u}
>   libjaxp1.3-java{u} libjetty-java{u} libjline-java{u} libjsch-java{u}
>   libjtidy-java{u} liblucene2-java{u} libpthread-stubs0{u}
>   libpthread-stubs0-dev{u} libregexp-java{u} libservlet2.4-java{u}
>   libservlet2.5-java{u} libslf4j-java{u} libsm-dev{u} libx11-dev{u}
>   libxau-dev{u} libxcb1-dev{u} libxdmcp-dev{u} libxerces2-java{u}
>   libxt-dev{u} linux-headers-2.6.32-38{u}
>   linux-headers-2.6.32-38-generic{u} openjdk-6-jre{u}
>   openjdk-6-jre-headless{u} openjdk-6-jre-lib{u} realpath{u} sat4j{u}
>   ttf-dejavu-extra{u} tzdata-java{u}    x11proto-core-dev{u}
>   x11proto-input-dev{u} x11proto-kb-dev{u} xtrans-dev{u}

Is it safe to go ahead when so many dependencies are being removed? Why is it prompting for removal of these dependencies?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Aptitude is very broken on 64-bit Ubuntu at the moment. This is due to the fact that it doesn't handle Multiarch. If this is your case, i.e. if you are running 64-bit, please just use apt-get instead for a while.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you currently have openjdk-6 installed, with ancillary third party libraries, and Sun (now Oracle)'s package wants to have its own versions of these libraries.

Suggest you read carefully the [following](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java#Oracle_.28Sun.29_Java_6) on Oracle's Java 6 and then `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to update your Java alternatives - see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) for the full community documentation on Java options available to you.

I would follow the community documentation directions and not do `aptitude install sun-java6-jdk`.

EDIT: have just seen OVC's answer and would try his/her suggestion first :-)